# Influence random spawning

Tags: ios, swift

So I got my game, which has 4 lanes, heading from bottom to top, in which are helmets spawning forever in a amount of time. 
I want to check if at least one of the 4 helmets spawning contains an object I gave him.
This is my code for the lane spawning in Lane.swift:

```
private func spawnRandomHelmet(){
        let helmet = HelmetNode(fruit: .random())
        helmet.delegate = self
        helmet.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 - helmet.size.height)
        addChild(helmet)

        let moveHelmetUp = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height - 285 - (helmet.size.height - 100), duration: self.config.helmetSpeed)
        helmet.run(moveHelmetUp) {
            let moveHelmetToScreenEnd = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + helmet.size.height, duration: 0.5)
            let fadeOutHelmet = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5)
            let moveAndFadeOut = SKAction.group([moveHelmetToScreenEnd, fadeOutHelmet])
            helmet.run(moveAndFadeOut) {
                helmet.removeFromParent()
                self.delegate?.removed(helmet.fruit)
            }
        }
    }

    public func startSpawning() {
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: config.delayDuration, withRange: config.delayVariance)
        let spawnHelmet = SKAction.run(spawnRandomHelmet)
        let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawnHelmet])
        let spawnForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnSequence)
        run(spawnForever)
    }
```

I call the function in my class GameScene.swift:

```
private func setUpLanes() {
    //Remove lanes from latest round
    for lane in [firstLane, secondLane, thirdLane, fourthLane] {
        lane.removeFromParent()
    }
    //Add lanes for current round
    for lane in [firstLane, secondLane, thirdLane, fourthLane] {
        lane.delegate = self
        addChild(lane)
        lane.startSpawning()
    }
}
```

I don't get how to check, if one helmets contains my object im looking for. There is an object I'm giving to the helmets randomly, every spawning.
This is how I add the Object to the helmet:

```
class HelmetNode: SKSpriteNode {
weak var delegate: HelmetNodeDelegate?
let fruit: Fruit

init(fruit: Fruit) {
    self.fruit = fruit
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "helmet \(fruit.name)")
    let size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 250)
    super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: size)
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    zPosition = 2
    anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

static func random(count: Int = 4) -> [HelmetNode] {
    var helmets: [HelmetNode] = []
    for _ in 1...count  {
        helmets.append(HelmetNode(fruit: .random()))
    }
    return helmets
}
```

Comment: When/where would you like to check for the object? Do you have an example?

Comment: Lack of relevant tags...

Comment: Please keep the community updated and provide feedback on answers. If you don’t have an answer yet, it’s because you don’t have enough information.

Comment: I want to check for the object before the helmets start moving upwards. I want to prevent that you have to wait like 10-20 seconds for a right object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the object as a child of helmet, then add a name to the object

```
object.name = “special object”
```

Then run:

```
for child in self.children {
    print(child.name)
}
```

when the helmet is spawned (but after the object should be added)

Comment: I did post how I add the object to the helmet.